# Cannot start Mysql-server Service

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mysql-error-1064

I have an issue, I can not start `mysql` service and how to configure mysql-server. I forgot password and username for mysql-server.
Excuse me for my weak English.

[**screenshot-issue**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufv84.png)

Comment: If you forgot your password and username and don't have made anything yet,then I would suggest to de-install and installing again, creating another user root

Answer (score 0):

If your case is just forgot password see then doc [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html) .
Or remove mysql then reinstall may solve your problem.

Remove mysql:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo mysql_install_db
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

And just check your disk isn't full.